# Reading in a text file with comma's

Tags: c

I am trying to use fscanf to read in from infile (which is either stdin or a file) for a file that is represented like this:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Do ignore the fact that they are numbers - I am representing them as strings.

What I did was I used

```
fscanf(infile, "%s%*c %s%*c %s%*c[^\n]", x, y, z); where x, y, z are string variables.
```

I am expecting that each represent digit, on that line, gets stored in x, y, z, but it is not working, and is instead storing the entire line in x alone.

Any help please? Thanks.

Comment: there are many o line tools to check regular expresions: http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Comment: @Asaf `scanf` doesn't use regular expressions.

Comment: You're probably better off reading an entire line with `fgets` (or `getline` if available) and tokenizing it with `strtok`. `scanf` (and `fscanf`) are notoriously hard to use correctly.

Comment: I must use fscanf or scanf for this sadly!

Comment: @jamesdli... i ignored the scanf part. maybe he should store the results of the scan f in an array and just then test if a string pass his regular expression test... but it seems that something is wrong with the regular expression

Answer (score 1):

You are using '%s' which will read an entire word upto spaces. So `1,2,3` is read in `x` for the first line.

What you need to do is take `x`, `y` and `z` as integers, Then you can read three integers and convert it to a string using a variety of methods (e.g. `itoa`

```
int x,y,z;
char x_str[20], y_str[20], z_str[20];
//...
fscanf(infile, "%d,%d,%d", x, y, z);
itoa{x,x_str,10);  // and so on
```

Comment: Without loss of generalization z is actually a string, it is a string of both words and numbers.

Comment: In that case, you can use `fscanf(infile, "%d,%d,%s", x, y, z_str);` to read a line of the file. `z_str` is a string and is directly read.

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* use `scanf`/`fscanf`, then you want to use `%[^,]` as the input formatter instead of `%s`. `%s` will greedily read as much as it can; `%[^,]` will read a string consisting of characters (including whitespace) that are not `,`:

```
fscanf(infile, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]", x, y, z);
```

Do note that the above usage of `fscanf` is *unsafe* because it does nothing to limit the number of characters read into each string.  Consequently, it is completely susceptible to buffer-overflow attacks.

---

Personally, I would read the entire line with `fgets` (or `getline` if available) and then tokenize it on `,` with `strtok`. [`scanf`/`fscanf` are notoriously hard to use correctly](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) and usually should be avoided.

Comment: If it's in the format of the OP (x,y,z\n), you'd want something like `"%[^,],%[^,],%[^\n] "`, perhaps with spaces after the commas. Which I guess just makes your point :)